# Problems trying to intersect two shapefiles

Tags: qgis, envi

I keep having problems trying to intersect two shapefiles.

One of them is a normal file that I downloaded from geoamenagement.com. The other I created by using the classification protocol tool on an image of a region ENVI 5.3, and then I saved the map as a shapefile. Whenever I try to intersect the two files, I get this error

> Feature (155131) of “Forest” has invalid geometry. Please repair the geometry or change the processing setting in the "Ignore invalid input features" option.

or sometimes I get an empty file.

NB: I'm using QGIS 3.28.2

Comment: Did you consider repairing the geometry layer or setting the "Ignore invalid input features" flag?

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/handling_invalid_geometries.html